# my function doesn't acces the arguments correctly in kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm doing a simple problem rock, scissors, paper, lizard and spock from this page https://retosdeprogramacion.com/semanales2023

I create a function call whoWins() that basicly returns the next string "P1" if the player 1 wins, "P2" if the player 2 wins or "Tie"... you know in what case XD

```kotlin
fun whoWins(game: Array<String>): String {
    
    var chooseP1 = game.get(0)
    var chooseP2 = game.get(1)
    
    println("Choose is ok : $chooseP1 and the type is: "+ chooseP1::class.simpleName)
    println("Choose is ok : $chooseP2 and the type is: "+ chooseP2::class.simpleName)
    
    var rules: MutableMap<String, ArrayList<String>> = mutableMapOf(
        "rock" to arrayListOf("scissors", "lizard"),
        "scissors" to arrayListOf("paper", "lizard"),
        "lizard" to arrayListOf("spock", "paper"),
        "paper" to arrayListOf("spock", "rock"),
        "spock" to arrayListOf("scissors", "rock")
    )
    
    if (chooseP1 == chooseP2) return "Tie"
    
    println("\nhere for some reason it returns null, HELP! "+ rules[chooseP1]+"\n")
    
    rules[chooseP1]?.forEach {
        if (it == chooseP2) {
            return "P1"
        }
    }
    
    return "P2"
    
}
```

for some reason the system returns null when i try to access the map with the var,

Now in order to save the different round of my game the problem use an Array, but when I access the method `whoWins()` the system return always "P2" , but when I use the method with string directly declared in the function it works fine, here is my main function

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) { 
    
    var game1 = mapOf<String, Array<String>>( "round1" to arrayOf("rock", "scissors️"), "round2" to arrayOf("scissors️", "rock"), "round3" to arrayOf("paper", "scissors️") ) 
    
    var game2 = arrayOf( arrayOf("rock", "scissors️"), arrayOf("scissors️", "rock"), arrayOf("paper", "scissors️"), arrayOf("spock", "scissors️"), arrayOf("lizard️", "spock"), arrayOf("spock", "rock️") )
    
    println("the var  ${game1.get("round1")!!.get(0)} type is: "+game1.get("round1")!!.get(0)::class.simpleName)
    
    println("Game 1 " + whoWins(game1.get("round1")!!))
    println("Game 2 " + whoWins(game2.get(0)!!))
    println("But the function is working fine: " + whoWins(arrayOf("rock", "scissors")))
    /*
        for (game in game2){
            if(whoWins(game.get(0),game.get(1)) == "P1"){
                pointsP1++
            }else{
                pointsP2++
            }
        }
    
        println(
            if (pointsP1 == pointsP2) "Tie"
            else if (pointsP1 > pointsP2) "Player 1"
            else "Player 2"
        )
    */
}
```

in this case the function should returns in this specific cases "P1", but here is the output

```
the var rock type is: StringChoose is ok : rock and the type is: StringChoose is ok : scissors️ and the type is: String

here for some reason it returns null, HELP! null

Game 1 P2Choose is ok : rock and the type is: StringChoose is ok : scissors️ and the type is: String

here for some reason it returns null, HELP! null

Game 2 P2Choose is ok : rock and the type is: StringChoose is ok : scissors and the type is: String

here for some reason it returns null, HELP! [scissors, lizard]

But the function is working fine: P1
```

so... I really don't have any idea what's going on, thanks in advance

I already try with `HashMap`, `Map` and `MutableMap` in `whoWins()` option

Comment: [If you remove the emojis it looks like it works](https://pl.kotl.in/5XOwsGY8t). Instead of using strings for the options, try [defining an enum](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/enum-classes.html) - because enums are strongly-typed there's less chance of a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you're using emoji in your input strings, which don't match the keys in your map. `rules["rock"]` does **not** match `"rock"` so you get *null*, because there's no entry with that key.

That means that this:

```
rules[chooseP1]?.forEach {
    if (it == chooseP2) {
        return "P1"
    }
}
    
return "P2"
```

will evaluate to *null* for each `chooseP1` that contains emoji, and skip the `forEach` block for that entry. If `chooseP1` *is* in `rules`, then it will only return `"P1"` if the returned value matches `chooseP2` - which it never will if `chooseP2` contains emoji (again, nothing in the map has them!)

Your code which *does* work just uses the plain strings, which do match:

```
// no emoji here
whoWins(arrayOf("rock", "scissors"))
```

---

Ideally for this kind of thing you'd be doing input sanitation anyway - if the user types `"Rock"` or `"ROCK"` or something that isn't *exactly* `"rock"`, you might want to make sure you accept that by converting it to the stored format for comparion (e.g. making it lowercase, stripping out all non-letter characters). And you could make sure it handles emoji too, by stripping them out or recognising them as "rock" or whatever

What you might want instead is a menu, say with numbers for each choice, a single letter like `r` for `rock`, that kind of thing. That's easier to parse, reject as invalid input, and convert to an internal representation. And you can display emoji on your menu if that's what you want!

Comment: Sorry, that emoji is not in the original code, I dont know why stackoverflow add it, also its my fisrt time asking here, but well, just picture that the emoji is not there and also right now I try to do this with .toLowerCase() and change to capital the entrys and inside the function is all in lowercase but is still not working

Comment: @IsmaelMatiz your function works fine when you call it with that last `[scissors, lizard]` array - so your problem isn't the function, it's what you're passing to it in the earlier calls. I don't know what's happening with the emoji but StackOverflow won't randomly insert things like that, so you should probably look into where they're coming from. If I were you I'd delete and retype those strings when you set up `game1` etc, so they definitely only have plain text and there's no hidden emoji characters or anything like that.